# HTTP запрос на картинки

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Я пытаюсь реализовать своего телеграмм-бота на node js. Дошёл до того этапа, когда мне нужно осуществить генерацию рандомных мемов. Я понимаю, что нужно найти какой-нибудь сайт с мемными картинками и запросить (с помощью http req) у него все элементы img, потом их скинуть пользователю телеграмм. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данную задумку.

Api для бота : node-telegram-bot-api

кусок кода, где всё реализуется :

```
else if (msg.text.startsWith('Перемена ')) {
            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Правильно! Возьми перерыв, иначе тебе может стать хуже ', {
                reply_markup:{
                    keyboard: [
                        ['Общий чатик ', 'Скинь мечики ⭐']
                    ],
                    resize_keyboard: true
                }
            })
        } 
else if (msg.text.startsWith('Общий чатик '))
{
    await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Отдохни и пообщайся с ребятами \nНаше комьюнити не позволит тебе заскучать!\n\nhttps://t.me/PupilsHelperChat')
}
```